# VBScript, Issues trying to use a number with SendKeys

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a simple vbsript in order to achieve CTRL+0 combination.
But it doesn't work. I've also searched other questions and looked to the Microsoft's page about the subject, but couldn't get anywhere.
This is the script, which does not work.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "^0"
```

And I dont really want to use AutoHotkey or any stuff like that, I want to keep it as simple as possible thus I choosed VBS.
Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: Which window do you think will receive the ctrl-0, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: `CTRL+0` won't type anything. Answer @Stefan answer, so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ManishChristian Thanks for your replies guys. It doesn't matter which window. CTRL+0 is a hotkey for another application I run at background. So just a CTRL+0 is okay for me and thats what I need, thanks. I mean I dont want it to type anything, I just need a simple vbs file which sends the CTRL+0 combination, while "^0" seems like it should work and do what I need, it doesn't. Hope Im more clean on the subject now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your reply, please see the comment above, regards.

Comment: And I should add that the application I'm talking about doesn't require to be the ActiveWindow to recieve the hotkey. Normally even though I'm on desktop or in another program, hotkey works.

Comment: Try **`WshShell.SendKeys("^(0)")`**.

Comment: @ManishChristian Thanks a lot but still doesn't work, so weird

Comment: As you said your application runs in background then how you would your VbScript know that it needs to send these key combination to that application? Have you covered that part anywhere in your script?

Comment: @ManishChristian No, but I also noted that the app I'm talking about doesn't require to be the ActiveWindow to recieve the hotkey. For example when Im on the Desktop or in Firefox or in anything else, when I press CTRL+0 manually, it works and the app recieves it, again thanks for your reply